# Checkbox won't check IE8

Tags: html, forms, checkbox, internet-explorer-8

I can't find a way to make the checkboxes checked in IE8. It's based on a Google Form, I re-used the same code to easily have an answer sheet. On top of that, the answers aren't sent.

I use this code

```
<li class="ss-choice-item">
<label>
<span class="ss-choice-item-control goog-inline-block">
<input type="checkbox" name="entry.637692828" value="Facebook" id="group_637692828_2" role="checkbox" class="ss-q-checkbox">
<label for="group_637692828_2"></label>
</span>
<span class="ss-choice-label">Facebook</span>
</label>
</li>
```

Here is the CSS, I wanted to custom the buttons, it works really fine in all other browsers.

```
.ss-q-checkbox {
    display: none;
}
.ss-q-checkbox + label {
    background-color: #fafafa;
    border: 1px solid #cacece;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), inset 0px -15px 10px -12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    padding: 9px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 4px;
}
.ss-q-checkbox + label:active, .ss-q-checkbox:checked + label:active {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), inset 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.ss-q-checkbox:checked + label {
    background-color: #e9ecee;
    border: 1px solid #adb8c0;
    color: #f87000;
}
.ss-q-checkbox:checked + label:after {
    content:'\2714';
    font-size: 14px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 3px;
    color: #f87000;
}
```

Could someone have the solution?
Thanks :)

Comment: Solution to what? What isn't working?

Comment: close your input tag. see this: http://jsfiddle.net/KwHTk/

Comment: @Alexander Think it's clear that he's asking why the checkbox won't tick when clicked in IE8

Comment: I updated my question, I'm not able to check the checkboxes

Comment: Thank you Ashish but it still doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: @jumpingcode I don't know whether he wants to click the checkbox (if so, this code clearly does not hold any reason for that behaviour) or whether he wants to have it pre-checked (checked="checked" is missing, but I don't see why he couldn't have found that one on google!?).

Comment: The issue is probably caused by CSS code that was not disclosed at all in the question, or maybe by JavaScript code. Post a *complete* (but preferably minimal) example that actually reproduces the issue.

Comment: It's when I want to click, but I even tried to pre-check the checkbox with "checked" inside the input but it doesn't work anyway

Comment: full code with the css would help - since IE8 does not support all css or. javascript

Comment: I've updated the question, I haven't any javascript used for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `display:none` (or `visibility:hidden`) on inputs with IE8 as it will treat it as if the input isn't there. Instead of hiding it using `display` try the following:

```
.ss-q-checkbox {
    position:fixed; left:100%; top:0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I had hope with that but it still doesn't work

Comment: @Moreno it may be because you have nested labels - this is invalid html, also what happens if you remove all css from the checkbox? does it work?

Comment: Yes it's working when I remove the CSS. I think that I have to forget the custom style for our old friend ie8

Comment: @Moreno I think also ie8 doesn't support the `:checked` pseudo-selector so you may need to look into using js for ie8 if you really want the custom styles - I usually use a [jquery plugin](http://line25.com/articles/jquery-plugins-for-styling-checkbox-radio-buttons)